# signed values Simulator ARMsim#

Tags: assembly, arm, simulator, microprocessors

I'm using ARMSim v1.9.1 and I have problems with this code:

> .data
>
> NUMBER: .word -120
>
> .text
>
> _start:
>
> ldr r0, =NUMBER
> ldrsb r1, [r0] @ sign extension
> ldrb r2, [r0] @ no sign extension
> .end

The problem is that I don't get sign extension in the first case. I get the same value than in the second one (0x88).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how does the whole register looks like? isn't it like 0x00000088 vs 0xFFFFFF88

Comment: 0x00000088, it doesn't extend the sign.

Comment: Try `ldr` instead of `ldrsb`; Or at least use `.byte` instead of `.word` to define the *-120*.